# Pausing queues in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

We recently moved to VSTS from TFS. One feature we often used is to pause queues whenever required. It was quite useful to prevent build failures in gated check in’s for known environment issues. Ex: specific tests or external dependencies failures or resources issues etc.,

I don’t see an option on how to pause a definition in VSTS.  Wondering if anyone has suggestions or work arounds ?

Answer (score 0):

There is the button of Cancel that can cancel the building.

[image]

You also can cancel the building through REST API: [Update a build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#update-a-build).

```
PATCH https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version={version}
```

Content-type (application/json)

```
{
    "status":"cancelling"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pause any build step in your definition.
[Puase task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwGJm.png)

If you want to pause entire definition then you can pause all the build steps.

Answer (score 0):

Now in VSTS you can Pause a build definition from the Brelease/Build menu. Select the defnition you want to Pause and click on the [...] on the right of it, then click on Pause:

[image]